# AutoMapper one to many relation

Tags: automapper, one-to-many

I'm starting to use AutoMapper for my project.

For this I want to do the following 'one-to-many' mapping:

Source:

```
public class Team
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string TeamName { get; set; }
    List<Person> Member { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Destination:

```
public class TeamDetailsViewModel
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string TeamName { get; set; }
    List<int> MemberIds { get; set; }
}
```

How to proceed with AutoMapper? Is this possible?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This map should work for you:

```
CreateMap<Team, TeamDetailsViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d=>d.MemberIds, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.Member.Select(m=>m.Id)));
```

FYI...If you are getting the Team from a db, make sure you are eager loading the Member list.