# how to map one-to-many relationship with custom mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm learning on how to use `AutoMapper` and I'm getting the hang of it. But what if you have a one-to-many relationship? You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872610/automapper-one-to-many-relation), right?

But then, what if the scenario was something like this wherein you only want the last value in the list. Let me demonstrate it.

```
public class Item
{
  public Item()
  {
    Prices = new HashSet<Price>();
  }
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ItemId { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }

  public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class ItemVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the catch is I want to map the `ItemVM.Price` = `The last value in Price class`. Is this possible?

I have tried something like this, but didn't worked.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemVM>()
  .ForMember(dto => dto.Price, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Prices.LastOrDefault().Price));
```

then

`var items = All.Project().To<ItemVM>();`

But gives me an error of InvalidOperation. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you define `the last value`?  By date, or Id?

Comment: I want to get the last value in the list of `Item.Prices` by `Price.ItemId`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mapping looks good, but maybe you are getting a `NullReferenceException`. I would map it that way:

[Edited]

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemVM>()
.ForMember(dto => dto.Price, opt => 
           opt.MapFrom(s => s.Prices.Any()?
           s.Prices.OrderByDescending ().First ().Price:0));
```

Comment: What does `?s` and `:0` do for? I'm new in `Linq` by the way. Think you could enlighten me more? It would be a great help.

Comment: `a?x:y`  means `if (a) x; else b;`. In this case it assings zero if the collection does not have any item. That prevents the exception.

Comment: Ohhh! A `ternary operator` Didn't realize that. I thought it was on linq itself. But I tried yours but gives me an `System.NotSupportedException`. Really stuck here. Been banging my head since last night.

Comment: In that case you might be getting something like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253529/last-and-lastordefault-not-supported . Then try to change `LastOrDefault` and use `Reverse().First ()`, `OrderByDescending ().First ()` or something like this?

Comment: WOW! It actually works! Thank you so much mate. Now I can move on. Really. Thank you so much. Think you can add that in the answer above? For other's reference :)